# Async class is not functioning inside fragment

Tags: android, class, asynchronous, fragment

When i installed in diffrenet mobiles i got dissimilar results. In android 8.0 its not functioning at all,but for android verstion 6,7 and 9 it works fine...even the toast message doesnt pop up in 8.0 here is the Async function

```
 public void Send_Messgae_overHTTP(final String name,final   String title,final String desc)
{

    class Send_Messgae_overHTTP extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onPreExecute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),httpResponseMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {

            hashMap.put("name",params[0]);
            hashMap.put("title",params[1]);
            hashMap.put("description",params[2]);

            finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURL);

            return finalResult;
        }
    }

    Send_Messgae_overHTTP send_messgae_overHTTP = new Send_Messgae_overHTTP();

    send_messgae_overHTTP.execute(name,title,desc);
}
```

Comment: you know async tasks are deprecated, right ?

Comment: ya sure! but can u suggest me advicable approaches?